# Automapper failing on double? property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, automapper-2

I'm using AutoMapper to map Domain objects to ViewModel objects in my controller.  Everything was working fine until I **tried adding double?** properties.  I've started getting the following error:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Address -> AddressModel
Domain.Address -> Web.Models.AddressModel

Destination path:
AccountAddressModel.Address.Address

Source value:
Domain.Address
```

My Address class and AddressModel class both have two properties called Longitude and Latitude.  These properties (in both classes) are defined as double?.  If I comment out these properties, everything works fine.  If I make all of these properties simply double, then everything works fine.  It's only double? that causes the problem.

I'm using **AutoMapper 2.2.1** downloaded via NuGet.

I've read in other posts that this problem with nullables was supposed to be fixed.  This leads me to believe I might be doing something different so I'm going to post my code to see if anyone can see something that might be an issue:

**DOMAIN MODELS**

```
public class AccountAddress 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Address : IUserTrackingEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Addressee { get; set; }
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public double? Latitutde { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW MODELS**

```
public class AccountAddressEditModel
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public AccountAddressModel Address { get; set; }
    public IList<Country> CountriesList { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AccountAddressModel
{
    public AccountAddressModel()
    {
        Address = new AddressModel();
    }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Addressee { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="A street address is required.")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

**MAPPING CODE IN MY CONTROLLER**

```
//Get an AccountAddress
address = _context.AccountAddresses.SingleOrDefault(ad => ad.Id == 12345);

model = new AccountAddressEditModel();

Mapper.CreateMap<AccountAddress, AccountAddressModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountAddress, AddressModel>();

Mapper.Map(address, model.AccountAddress);
```

Has anyone else experienced this or found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<AccountAddress, AddressModel>();
```

should be changed to

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressModel>();
```

This because you are mapping the `Address` class to the `AddressModel` class.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks tons!  Weird that it was working the other way until I added those double? properties.